# Black screen on login page

Tags: unity, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

When I startup my Ubuntu 12.04 installed on a Z77 Pro4 (ASrock motherboard), crucial M4 SSD drive (sata 3), and intel i5 3570k (ivy bridge), I get this black login screen :
[image]

I also hear the ubuntu login sound "tic toc" but the screen is black, and if I type in some text, only strange characters appears (as you can see on the picture).

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

ps : this is an evolution of a previous problem exposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185174/black-login-screen-ubuntu-12-04-if-wga-cable-pluged-in-on-reboot)

Comment: You will find the answer of my problem here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/229050/need-restart-lightdm-at-every-startup-console-login-screen