# Need restart lightdm at every startup - console login screen

Tags: 12.10, login, lightdm, login-screen

Everytime I boot up my ubuntu 12.10, I get a black console screen.

I need to login in tty, and restart lightdm : `sudo service lightdm restart`

Then the GUI lightdm login screen appears as expected.

How to solve this annoying problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the kernel from the proposed pocket? There was [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1087622) that prevented the system to boot properly.

Comment: My kernel is 3.5.0-19-generic and my architecture 64bits. So I don't think i encountered this bug...anyway, I found a way to solve that annoying problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue could be related to the use of a SSD.

If the first solution doesn't work for you, another workaround is to delay the startup of lightdm.

```
sudo nano /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

and just BEFORE ***exec lightm***, insert this single line :

```
sleep 2
```

Adjust the time (in seconds) depending on your needs (2 sec works for me). Save the file,  and restart !

Found this solution here : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html

Comment: I've had the same problem on two notebooks with SSD drives. I had to use `sleep 2` (`delay` is not installed on my Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: oups, you're right. the command is sleep, and not delay. Updated ! thx

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I solved the problem by :

- installing GDM: `sudo apt-get install gdm`
- choosing it by default: `When asked, choose GDM as your default X windows manager`
- restarting: `sudo reboot`
- Reverting to **lightdm** as default *X window manager*: `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Ps : firing the command `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` without having installed GDM before didn't solve my problem. So try installing GDM before.

Comment: same issue exists on 32-bit.  i don't know how i got to this state, though.  i had both gdm and lightdm before i tried your fix (changing to gdm and back to lightdm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are booting windows 7 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS i have same problem then i tried everything referred from sites.finally nothing is worked for me.
 so one thing is worked for me.

1. do not choose the default ubuntu os.
2. click on advanced option for ubuntu
3. choose the os option like "Ubuntu 16.04 .....(Systemed)"

this will boot your ubuntu os normally. and it works for me also it saves your time to everytime restart lightdm service.